# How to crawl Twitter pages using Python?

Tags: python, twitter, python-2.7

When I try to crawl Twitter using this code:

```
import urllib2
s = "https://mobile.twitter.com/bing/"
html = urllib2.urlopen(s).read()
print html
```

... I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arpit\Downloads\Desktop\Wiki Code\final Crawler_wiki.py", line 14, in <module>
    html = urllib2.urlopen(s).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

If I replace `mobile.twitter.com` with `twitter.com` then it works, but I want it to work with `mobile.twitter.com`.

Comment: Why are you crawling the mobile twitter site?  Twitter has a well documented API that  gives you everything, and there are many Python client libraries for it.

Answer (score 0):

The twitter site is probably looking for a user-agent which you dont have set when you make the request through the urllib api.

You will likely need to use something like [mechanize](http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/) to fake your user-agent.

But I highly suggest your use the [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/) which provide a lot of  easy and awesome way to play with data.

Comment: I have also tried the Python-twitter Api and Twython. Both give the same error code.I am behind a proxy and I guess thats causing troubles. 

I have posted a new q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951901/unable-to-get-data-using-python-twitter-api for twitter API also .

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal well I would mark this as resolved for people who want to scrape the twitter mobile with the firewall issues.